# Understand an example in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have trouble understanding an example in a ring theory's problem.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$, $J$ ideals in $R$. Give an
> example to prove the set {$ij; i\in I, j\in J$} not necessarily an
> ideal.

Here is the given example
[image]

How can I determine the evaluation of all polynomials of $I$ and $J$ on $(X1,X2,X3,X4)$ and why from the evaluation on $(X1,X2,X3,X4)$ the author can deduce $i, j$ are non-constant? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the notation here is a bit misleading. What the author means is that if you evaluate any polynomial in $I$, $J$ on $(x_1,x_2,x_2,x_4)=(0,0,0,0) \in \mathbb{C}^4$  the result is zero. Since $p(0)$ gives you the constant term of a polynomial, this implies that $i$, $j$ are not constant. Note that they can not be constantly $0$, because otherwise $i\cdot j$ would be zero.